# $.ajax {readyState=0} when I set 'contentType'

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, contenttype

I'm trying to deliver a JSON object via POST to validate some information. My $.ajax request returns {readystate=4} if I do not set a 'contentType' however it returns {readystate=0} if I do set one. My code currently looks like:

var hmo ={"Data": "myDataTest"};

```
            $.ajax({
               url: "http://www.testUrl.com",
               type: "Post",
               data: JSON.stringify(hmo),
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(msg){
                    if(msg){
                        alert("Success in posting! <br /><br />" + JSON.stringify(msg));
                    }
               },
               complete: function(data){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
               },
               contentType: "application/json",
            });
```

When it runs it returns:

{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Am I missing some other form of setting to ensure that the $.ajax request goes through?

Comment: What is the `error` being given? Most browsers will log the details in the console (dev tools). Is `http://testurl.com` [your own origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) or have they given your site permission to send Ajax requests to them?

Comment: I have set the $.ajax request to accept an 'error:' function in the past and it always returned "error" which wasn't very helpful. I do not get any error codes or further information.

And "http://www.testurl.com" is just an example url I put in this here as a placeholder, in my own code I am using an actual API Url.